# Openerp 7 openerp-server.conf custom addons_path

Tags: openerp-7, server-configuration

How can i add my custom addons to config? Here is my openerp-server.conf file

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = dev1
db_password = False
addons_path =/home/dev1/odoo-7.0/addons
```

and I am adding my custom addons to addons_path with a comma like that,

```
addons_path =/home/dev1/odoo-7.0/addons,/home/dev1/odoo-7.0/custom_addons
```

but it is giving me an 'web_kanban' error. What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the one add-ons path. We must need to include the openerp add-ons path in the config file.

```
/home/dev1/odoo-7.0/openerp
```

So, your file looks like below.

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = dev1
db_password = False
addons_path = /home/dev1/odoo-7.0/addons,/home/dev1/odoo-7.0/openerp, /home/dev1/odoo-7.0/custom_addons
```

This should work for you.